# Show full width column inside a Col-md-3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My expected design is like this
[image]

Each pod you see in top will have a corresponding inner hidden content with it. On that plus button click I will show it and the shown content need to take full width as in the image. Everything works fine except the inner content (class name `shower`) is not aligning full width. This is my code

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".cssCircle").click(function() {
     var id = $(this).attr('data-target');

     $(id).show();
   });
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container charity-listing">
  <ul style="list-style:none;">
    <li class="col-md-3 odd" style="width:22% !important ;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;margin:4px 4px 4px 4px">
      <div class="pod">
        <img style="position:inherit !important;right:0px !important;width:100%;max-width:100%;height:auto;" src="https://s16.postimg.org/c7m216tvp/images.png">
        <strong title="Charity test">Charity test</strong>
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore</p>
        <div class="cssCircle plusSign" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tabsec0">+</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 shower in" style="display:none" id="tabsec0" aria-hidden="false">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <!--WoW Slider End-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <h3>Charity test</h3>
          <p>
            <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>
            <span>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<br />is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
          </p>
          <p>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-3 odd" style="width:22% !important ;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;margin:4px 4px 4px 4px">
      <div class="pod">
        <img style="position:inherit !important;right:0px !important;width:100%;max-width:100%;height:auto;" src="https://s16.postimg.org/c7m216tvp/images.png">
        <strong title="Charity test">Charity test</strong>
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore</p>
        <div class="cssCircle plusSign" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tabsec0">+</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 shower in" style="display:none" id="tabsec0" aria-hidden="false">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <!--WoW Slider End-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <h3>Charity test</h3>
          <p></p>
          <p>
            <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>
            <span>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br />is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
          </p>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-3 odd" style="width:22% !important ;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;margin:4px 4px 4px 4px">
      <div class="pod">
        <img style="position:inherit !important;right:0px !important;width:100%;max-width:100%;height:auto;" src="https://s16.postimg.org/c7m216tvp/images.png">
        <strong title="Charity test">
                    Charity test
                </strong>
        <p>
          Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore
        </p>
        <div class="cssCircle plusSign" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tabsec0">
          +
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 shower in" style="display:none" id="tabsec0" aria-hidden="false">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <!--WoW Slider End-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <h3>
                        Charity test
                    </h3>
          <p>
          </p>
          <p>
            <strong>
                            Lorem Ipsum
                        </strong>
            <span>
                            is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br />
                            is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                        </span>
          </p>
          <p>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-3 odd" style="width:22% !important ;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;margin:4px 4px 4px 4px">
      <div class="pod">
        <img style="position:inherit !important;right:0px !important;width:100%;max-width:100%;height:auto;" src="https://s16.postimg.org/c7m216tvp/images.png">
        <strong title="Charity test">
                    Charity test
                </strong>
        <p>
          Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore
        </p>
        <div class="cssCircle plusSign" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tabsec0">
          +
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 shower in" style="display:none" id="tabsec0" aria-hidden="false">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <!--WoW Slider End-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <h3>
                        Charity test
                    </h3>
          <p>
          </p>
          <p>
            <strong>
                            Lorem Ipsum
                        </strong>
            <span>
                            is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br />
                            is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                        </span>
          </p>
          <p>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-3 odd" style="width:22% !important ;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;margin:4px 4px 4px 4px">
      <div class="pod">
        <img style="position:inherit !important;right:0px !important;width:100%;max-width:100%;height:auto;" src="https://s16.postimg.org/c7m216tvp/images.png">
        <strong title="Charity test">
            Charity test
        </strong>
        <p>
          Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore
        </p>
        <div class="cssCircle plusSign" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tabsec0">
          +
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 shower in" style="display:none" id="tabsec0" aria-hidden="false">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <!--WoW Slider End-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <h3>
                Charity test
            </h3>
          <p>
          </p>
          <p>
            <strong>
                    Lorem Ipsum
                </strong>
            <span>
                    is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br />
                    is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                </span>
          </p>
          <p>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone point out what I am missing here?

> CodePen version for better understanding http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBMYVx

Comment: So you want something like this, as the first box is showing here in updated codepen? http://codepen.io/sanjeevks121/pen/YpazbN, also shower class has two columns, first one is blank using col-md-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove col-md-4 and col-md-8 for full width 
Have a look on below code

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".cssCircle").click(function() {
     var id = $(this).attr('data-target');

     $(id).show();
   });
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container charity-listing">
  <ul style="list-style:none;">
    <li class="col-md-3 odd" style="width:22% !important ;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;margin:4px 4px 4px 4px">
      <div class="pod">
        <img style="position:inherit !important;right:0px !important;width:100%;max-width:100%;height:auto;" src="https://s16.postimg.org/c7m216tvp/images.png">
        <strong title="Charity test">
                    Charity test
                </strong>
        <p>
          Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore
        </p>
        <div class="cssCircle plusSign" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tabsec0">
          +
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 shower in" style="display:none" id="tabsec0" aria-hidden="false">
     
     
          <h3>
                        Charity test
                    </h3>
       ong>
                            Lorem Ipsum
                        </strong>
            <span>
                            is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br />
                             is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                        </span>
          </p>
        
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-3 odd" style="width:22% !important ;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;margin:4px 4px 4px 4px">
      <div class="pod">
        <img style="position:inherit !important;right:0px !important;width:100%;max-width:100%;height:auto;" src="https://s16.postimg.org/c7m216tvp/images.png">
        <strong title="Charity test">
                    Charity test
                </strong>
        <p>
          Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore
        </p>
        <div class="cssCircle plusSign" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tabsec0">
          +
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 shower in" style="display:none" id="tabsec0" aria-hidden="false">
      
     
          <h3>
                        Charity test
                    </h3>
          <p>
          </p>
          <p>
            <strong>
                            Lorem Ipsum
                        </strong>
            <span>
                            is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br />
                            is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                        </span>
          </p>
       
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-3 odd" style="width:22% !important ;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;margin:4px 4px 4px 4px">
      <div class="pod">
        <img style="position:inherit !important;right:0px !important;width:100%;max-width:100%;height:auto;" src="https://s16.postimg.org/c7m216tvp/images.png">
        <strong title="Charity test">
                    Charity test
                </strong>
        <p>
          Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore
        </p>
        <div class="cssCircle plusSign" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tabsec0">
          +
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 shower in" style="display:none" id="tabsec0" aria-hidden="false">
        
       
          <h3>
                        Charity test
                    </h3>
          <p>
          </p>
          <p>
            <strong>
                            Lorem Ipsum
                        </strong>
            <span>
                            is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br />
                            is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                        </span>
          </p>
          <p>
         
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-3 odd" style="width:22% !important ;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;margin:4px 4px 4px 4px">
      <div class="pod">
        <img style="position:inherit !important;right:0px !important;width:100%;max-width:100%;height:auto;" src="https://s16.postimg.org/c7m216tvp/images.png">
        <strong title="Charity test">
                    Charity test
                </strong>
        <p>
          Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore
        </p>
        <div class="cssCircle plusSign" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tabsec0">
          +
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 shower in" style="display:none" id="tabsec0" aria-hidden="false">
      
       
          <h3>
                        Charity test
                    </h3>
          <p>
          </p>
          <p>
            <strong>
                            Lorem Ipsum
                        </strong>
            <span>
                            is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br />
                            is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                        </span>
          </p>
      
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-3 odd" style="width:22% !important ;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;margin:4px 4px 4px 4px">
      <div class="pod">
        <img style="position:inherit !important;right:0px !important;width:100%;max-width:100%;height:auto;" src="https://s16.postimg.org/c7m216tvp/images.png">
        <strong title="Charity test">
            Charity test
        </strong>
        <p>
          Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore
        </p>
        <div class="cssCircle plusSign" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tabsec0">
          +
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 shower in" style="display:none" id="tabsec0" aria-hidden="false">
        
       
          <h3>
                Charity test
            </h3>
          <p>
          </p>
          <p>
            <strong>
                    Lorem Ipsum
                </strong>
            <span>
                    is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br />
                    is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                </span>
          </p>
        
        
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not working, Second row is not taking full width of the page as shown in image

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your shower div is inside col-md-3, so even if it is 100%, it will take 100% of its container, in this case 22%. If you cant place your shower outside the li elements, then you can do it with jQuery.

Get the index of the li to identify the row and then append the shower after the 4th li on that row, this way elements on other rows will show properly.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $(".cssCircle").click(function () {
     var id = $(this).attr('data-target');
     var index = $(this).closest("li").index();
     index = Math.floor(index/4)+3;
     $(id).insertAfter(".charity-listing ul li:eq("+index+")").show();
   });
 });
```

Here is the updated [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBxYeE)

Note this is an start, there a few more validations you need to add.